# Eloquent custom relationship hasMany (foreign field contains text concatenated by foreign key)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I have this database structure. 2 tables: `shipment_out`, `stock_move`.

`shipment_out` has the typical primary key integer id field.

`stock_move` has a field named `shipment` which is string type. This field can have these values:

```
"stock_shipment_out,1512",
"stock_shipment_in,65400",
"sale.line,358",
(...)
```

The thing is the table stock_move is related to a multiple tables based on the same field, so it has this text before.

In this case I want to define the relationship: `shipment_out` hasMany `stock_move`.
So I need to join by stock_move.shipment has this value: 'stock_shipment_out,{id}'.

So how can I define this relationship? Would be something like:

```
public function stockMoves()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockMove::class, 'shipment', 'stock.shipment.out,id');
}
```

I can achieve this relationship with query builder:

```
    $shipments = ShipmentOut
        ::join('public.stock_move', DB::raw('CONCAT(\'stock.shipment.out,\',public.stock_shipment_out.id)'), '=', 'stock_move.shipment')
        ->where('stock_shipment_out.id', '=', $shipmentOut);
```

But I need on a relationship too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to define a custom attribute, and then I can define the relationship with this field.

```
public function getStockMoveShipmentAttribute()
{
    return "stock.shipment.out,{$this->id}";
}

public function stockMoves()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockMove::class, 'shipment', 'stock_move_shipment')
}
```

Now I can use this relationship, but it's only one-direction...
If I want to define the same relationship as the inverse it doesn't work.

I opened another question explaining it: [Laravel relationship based on custom attribute not working both directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483032/laravel-relationship-based-on-custom-attribute-not-working-both-directions)