# Laravel relationship based on custom attribute not working both directions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, custom-attributes

Models Product and Category.

Product model has this custom attribute: `getCategoryIdAttribute()`. because the way to get category id is a bit complex.

With that attribute I can define the relationship (Product -> Category):

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

This relationship works fine!

But now on the Category model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

If I use this relationship it fails on SQL.

Example on tinker:

```
Product::first()->category; // Works!
Category::first()->products; // Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column products.category_id does not exist
```

Why when I use the relationship Product -> Category works but Category -> Products doesn't?

Comment: That error is informing you that the column `category_id` does not exist on your `products` table. You can't define a relationship on a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: But why the relationship defined on Product model works? Why in this case it's looking for the custom attribute category_id defined on Product model?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column products.category_id does not exist

Comment: Can you provide the table structure for `Product`?